# Downloading NetCDF files with R works Manually but downloaded file is smaller

Tags: r, netcdf, download

I am trying to download NetCDF files from: https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/NMME/prob/netcdf/

When I manually downloaded the files I got a file of about 5000 Kb, when it is downloaded with the code below I got a file of 119 Kb and it is not usable.

```
now <- as.Date(Sys.Date())
now <- paste0(substr(now,1,4),substr(now,6,7))
filename <- paste0('prate.',now,'.prob.adj.seas',".nc")
root <- 'https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/NMME/prob/netcdf/'
download.file(root, filename,mode = "wb")
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `download.file` is the thing you want to download, the second argument is the *local* filename to save it as.

You're doing this:

```
download.file(root, filename,mode = "wb")
```

which is downloading from `root`, which will get you the **file listing** that you can see if you go to https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/NMME/prob/netcdf/ and save it in the file given by `filename`. Instead you need to put the filename onto the root, which you can best do with `file.path`, and download that:

```
download.file(file.path(root, filename), filename, mode="wb")
```

which gets me a working ncdf file.